# Changing each data in dataframe using ifelse in R

Tags: r, if-statement

```
x = c("stage 1-1", "stage 2-2", "stage 3-2")
y = c("stage 1-1", "stage 1-2", "stage 2-2")
z = c("stage 3-2", "stage 2-1", "stage 3-4")

df <- data.frame(x, y, z)
```

I'm new in R, and I have this dataframe name as df. 
However, I want to change stage o-x to just stage o using if else.
For example, stage 2-2 to stage 2 or stage 3-4 to stage 3. 
Could you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

We may remove the substring with `trimws`

```
df[] <- lapply(df, trimws, whitespace = '-\\d+')
```

Comment: I believe `trimws` is vectorized. Thus `df[] <- trimws(as.matrix(df), whitespace = '-\\d+')` will suffice

Answer (score 1):

You can drop everything after `'-'` using `sub`.

```
sub('-.*', '', df$x)
#[1] "stage 1" "stage 2" "stage 3"
```

To apply this for all column you can use `lapply`.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) sub('-.*', '', x))
df

#        x       y       z
#1 stage 1 stage 1 stage 3
#2 stage 2 stage 1 stage 2
#3 stage 3 stage 2 stage 3
```

The same can be done using `across` in `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(across(.fns =  ~sub('-.*', '', .)))
```